# My Future builder "future" request don't get called when navigation back

Tags: flutter

I'm using a `FutureBuilder` to fetch some data from sqflite...
I have a function that got called when my screen is pushed on the top of the `navigation` stack... (it works fine)
But when I go to the next page and add a new record and then go back to the "entries" page (the page that is using the `FutureBuilder`) the function that fetch data is not firing again... what should I do to fetch again the records?

Look at my code:

```dart
body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _formEntrieService.getFormEntriesAlt(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  FormEntrie item = snapshot.data[index];
                  return Card(
                    elevation: 5,
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(item.insertDate.toString()),
                      leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text(item.id.toString())),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
```

Comment: Can you show how you are pushing and popping the next page on the `nav` stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call setState when you came back from navigator as following.

```
 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=> FireStoreGetData())).then((value){
            setState(() {

            });
          });
```